# Why does free() put random chunks of data instead of deleting a node?

Tags: c, hash, free

So, I'm studying hash tables and i'm on implementing one with an array and the collision resolving method being the chaining one. It seems to work well, but the deletion puts some random chunks of data in the place of the deleted item.
I'm using free(node) in order to delete a node.

Comment: It might help if you post code that shows the problem, as it is probably specific to that code. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve .

Comment: That's what free() might do on some platforms. However if you free() something, you shouldn't be looking at that item afterwards - there's no telling what you might see (and it's undefined behavior as well).

Comment: Memory can't be "deleted"--it's just there. Malloc/free do nothing but change ownership. Think of it like this: your computer's memory is like a big block of storage lockers. malloc() rents one of those lockers for you. free() cancels your contract. The locker is still there--you're just no longer allowed to care what's in it because it's not yours anymore.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess you probably wrote something like this:

```
free(bucket->node);
```

That statement frees the memory pointed to by `bucket->node`, which mean the memory can be returned later by a call to `malloc`, or it can be returned to the operating system.

Usually, unless the freed memory was quite large (like, megabytes), the memory is **not** returned to the operating system, for efficiency reasons.
So the memory is probably still accessible to your program through the `bucket->node` pointer, but after `free` returns, the content of the memory is undefined (and has probably been changed to store housekeeping information used by the allocator).

If you deference `bucket->node` after you called `free(bucket->node)`, you commit a “use-after-free” error. The effects of this error are undefined but can be very serious. It is your responsibility to not dereference `bucket->node` after passing it to `free`.

The usual way to avoid use-after-free is to immediately set the pointer to null. Example:

```
free(bucket->node);
bucket->node = 0;
```

Comment: Thank you, it clarified my problem and i managed to resolve it.